# sqlalchemy cascades save-update

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, cascade

There are four classes:
`Photo`, `Video`,`Audio` and `Post`. `Post` class has a field `attachments` which holds objects of first three types (photo, video, audio). 
I want to do the following: whenever I add `post` object using `session.add(post)` all elements of the `attachments` list are added too. 
I read about cascades http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/cascades.html?highlight=cascade
but I don't know how to use them in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you do something like:

```
session.add(post)
post.attachments.append(video_obj)
post.attachments.append(audio_obj)
```

the related objects will be persisted in db and should have session attached to them.

Comment: that's what I do now, but I am interested in a more elegant way rather than running a for loop

Comment: This is the proper way to attach related objects, it has nothing to do with loops. Just append the objects in the same place you create them.